# Android Cordova - How to draw photo taken on canvas?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

i'm working with an hybrid Android app and I need to take a picture from camera, process the image and then show the results obtained on another window that should contain a small preview of the picture taken and some text with the results.
Here is the relevant code that is not currently working as I need:

From script of first window:

```
    .
    .
    .
    CameraPreview.takePicture(function(imgData){
      var mImage = new Image();
      mImage.onload = function(){    
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = mImage.width;
        canvas.height = mImage.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(mImage, 0, 0);
        var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        .
        .(Process imgData[])
        .
        localStorage.setItem("resultImage", mImage.src);        
        window.open('result.html','_blank','location=no');
      };

      mImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+imgData;

   });
```

Then, "result.html" pops up, which has the following html content:

```
    ...
    <body>
      ...
      <canvas id="resultCanvas" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%;"></canvas>
      ...
    </body>
    ...
```

And the following javascript code:

```
    ...
    var mImage = new Image();      
    mImage.onload = function(){    
      var canvas = document.getElementById('resultCanvas');
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight*0.3; // 1/3 of phone screen size
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
      context.drawImage(mImage);
      navigator.notification.alert('Height = '+mImage.height+'\n'+'Width ='+mImage.width, function(){},'Image','Done');
    };
    mImage.src = localStorage.getItem("resultImage");
    ...
```

The alert window shows the 640x480 of the image, but the canvas is transparent where it should contain the picture taken.
If I replace the "context.drawImage()" statement with "context.fillrect()" I can see the black rectangle drawn on screen, so it looks that the canvas is there, but somehow I can not make it draw the desired image.

Hope I explained myself correctly.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solved it, first I tryied using an "img" element instead of a canvas, and that works fine, but the problem is I need to make some drawings over the picture, so insisting on code I posted before, I realized the problem was on the use of drawImage() method in the second script, it is necessary to specify position, so replacing:

```
   context.drawImage(mImage);
```

with

```
   context.drawImage(mImage,0,0);
```

solved everything.